# is JTextPane an acceptable client of JScrollPane?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextpane

I have JTextArea working with scroll bars provided by JScrollPane.  Following that pattern I have not been able to get JTextPane to show up with scroll bars.

Essentially I attach text to the JScrollPane as follows:

```
myJScrollPane.setViewportView(myJTextArea); // does not work with myJTextPane, 
                                            // an instance of JTextPane
```

No exception is thrown, the scroll bars, both horizontal and vertical simply do not appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
JScrollPane myJScrollPane = new JScrollPane(myJTextArea);
myJScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
```

Comment: This causes the vertical scroll bar to appear but only when the enclosing panel is big (ironically).  And when it is big, you don't need to scroll.

Comment: I suppose you have solved the problem since the vertical scroll bar does show up.  I will select this as the answer and start a new question to address the creation of a scrollable JTextPane.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether setPreferredSize() was not called and preferred size isn't set for the JTextPane.

Comment: setPreferredSize is not called.